# How To get the Sum of values derived from range sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a budget slider and essentially I am looking to get the sum of all the values determined by the sliders.

I can't figure out where I am missing a step. The idea is to let users set their expenses in each category and at the end, they will see the sum of all of their expenses.

You can see an example of the snippet below.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var sliders = document.getElementById("therange");
var result = document.getElementById("num");
result.innerHTML = this.value;

sliders.oninput = function() {
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var sliderss = document.getElementById("yrange");
var answer = document.getElementById("transport");
answer.innerHTML = this.value;

sliderss.oninput = function() {
  answer.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var sliderm = document.getElementById("mrange");
var res = document.getElementById("misc");
res.innerHTML = this.value;

sliderm.oninput = function() {

  res.innerHTML = this.value;
}
$(function() {
  $('input[type=range]').change(getTotal); // not () - you're not calling the function
  getTotal(); // initialy call it
});

function getTotal() {
  var first = document.getElementById("demo");
  var second = document.getElementById("num");
  var third = document.getElementById("transport");
  var fourth = document.getElementById("misc")
  total.innerHTML = this.gettotal; // here you used the slide slide1 without initializing them at all
}
```

```css
.budgetpanel {
  background-color: white;
  height: 650px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 75%;
  /* Width of the outside container */
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4caf50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4caf50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Budget</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider.css">
  <!-- <script src="slider.js"></script> -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <!-- rent -->
  <div class="budgetpanel">
    <h1> My Budget</h1>
    <p>Insert your expected monthly expenses.</p>

    <!-- Sliders -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Rent</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="5000" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Food -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Food</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" class="slider" id="therange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="num"></span></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Transportation -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Transportation</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" class="slider" id="yrange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="transport"></span></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Misc -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Misc</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" class="slider" id="mrange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="misc"></span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="totals">
      <p>Total $:<span id="total"></span></p>
    </div>


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getTotal()` needs to add up `first`, `second`, `third`, and `fourth`.

You're also using the wrong IDs in `getTotal()`, and you need to get the values of each of them.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var sliders = document.getElementById("therange");
var result = document.getElementById("num");
result.innerHTML = result.value;

sliders.oninput = function() {
  result.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var sliderss = document.getElementById("yrange");
var answer = document.getElementById("transport");
answer.innerHTML = answer.value;

sliderss.oninput = function() {
  answer.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var sliderm = document.getElementById("mrange");
var res = document.getElementById("misc");
res.innerHTML = res.value;

sliderm.oninput = function() {

  res.innerHTML = this.value;
}
$(function() {
  $('input[type=range]').change(getTotal); // not () - you're not calling the function
  getTotal(); // initialy call it
});

function getTotal() {
  var first = parseInt(slider.value) || 0;
  var second = parseInt(sliders.value) || 0;
  var third = parseInt(sliderss.value) || 0;
  var fourth = parseInt(sliderm.value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = first + second + third + fourth;
}
```

```css
.budgetpanel {
  background-color: white;
  height: 650px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slidecontainer {
  width: 75%;
  /* Width of the outside container */
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4caf50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4caf50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Budget</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider.css">
  <!-- <script src="slider.js"></script> -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <!-- rent -->
  <div class="budgetpanel">
    <h1> My Budget</h1>
    <p>Insert your expected monthly expenses.</p>

    <!-- Sliders -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Rent</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="5000" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Food -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Food</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" class="slider" id="therange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="num"></span></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Transportation -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Transportation</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" class="slider" id="yrange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="transport"></span></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Misc -->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Misc</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" class="slider" id="mrange">
      <p>Value $: <span id="misc"></span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="totals">
      <p>Total $:<span id="total"></span></p>
    </div>


  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTotal() {
  var first = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
  var second = document.getElementById("num").innerText;
  var third = document.getElementById("transport").innerText;
  var fourth = document.getElementById("misc").innerText;
  total.innerHTML = Number(first) + Number(second) + Number(third) + Number(fourth); 
}
```

.innerText returns the value in the numbers, convert String type to Number type, add them, and then set it as total.

Comment: You should also make sure the values are not "undefined" before casting them to a Number, otherwise you will end up with NaN as the total.